# Find string pattern

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an app that's looking for a string entered by a user. There will be a text file that's going to store a lot of strings and the app will be checking if the string can be found within this file and display the index of the string. In case the string can't be found, the app will look for specific patterns.

Here's an example of the text file:

```
This
This |
This is |
This car is #

| - one word
# - one or more words
```

How will the app work?

- If "This" is the string entered by the user, the app will display the index of the first line (0).
- If "This apple" is the string entered by the user, the app will display the index of "This |" (1).
- If "This is awesome" is the string entered by the user, the app will display the index of "This is |" (2).
- If "The car is blue and I like it" is the string entered by the user, the app will display the index of "This car is #" (3).

Usually, if I'm looking for a string I would use this code:

```
string[] grammarFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Text.txt");
int resp = Array.IndexOf(grammarFile, userString);
Console.WriteLine(resp);
```

The main problem is that I have no idea how I could do this for patterns.

Comment: The code you posted does *not* search for a string. It tries to find an *exact match* in an array. Have you checked the methods in the `String` class?

Comment: Hi. You should look into using regular expression. You can read your existing patterns and generate the correct regular expression, like `pattern.Replace("|", "(regex for finding word)")`

Comment: Since you know how `Array.IndexOf()` works, try creating a method that does the same (but traverses the array manually). This custom method will already answer the majority of your question. The current question suffers from lack of working out, I suspect you're going to attract downvotes/close votes unless you can add your own attempt at solving this.

Comment: There's no easy way to do what you're asking, so I suggest doing it in an easy to read way instead.  Start with what you have, get the string at the point that you find a match for "This" and take it from there.  You will probably want to use Regular Expressions to do the word matching (you don't have to, but it's a good thing to start using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a definition for a *word*. I will assume that a *word* is a consecutive string of any non-whitespace characters.

Let's define a regex that matches a single word:

```
var singleWordRegex = @"[^\s]+";
```

and a regex that matches one or more words (a sequence of non-whitespace characters, followed by a sequence of whitespace characters or the end of the string):

```
var oneOrMoreWordsRegex = @"([^\s]+([\s]|$)+)+";
```

Now you can transform each string from your textfile to a regex like this:

```
Regex ToRegex(this string grammarEntry)
{
    var singleWordRegex = @"[^\s]+";
    var oneOrMoreWordsRegex = @"([^\s]+([\s]|$)+)+";

    return new Regex("^" + grammarEntry.Replace("|", singleWordRegex).Replace("#", oneOrMoreWordsRegex) + "$" );
}
```

and test every grammar entry like this:

```
var userString = ReadUserString();
string[] grammarFile = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\user_name\Desktop\Text.txt");
var resp = -1;

for(int i = 0; i < grammarFile.Length; ++i)
{
    var grammarEntry = grammarFile[i];

    if(grammarEntry.ToRegex().IsMatch(userString))
    {
        resp = i;
        break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(resp);
```

On a side note, if you're going to perform many matches it might be wise to save all ToRegex calls to an array as preprocessing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, if I enter "This apple" / "This is awesome" / "This car is blue", it is going to return the index of the first line (0).

Comment: You are right. I have edited my answer to include the string begin/end characters (^, $).

Comment: Thank you for your response!